# Cartesian product from user input - getting strings not a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, cartesian-product

I'm working on an assignment and am partially there but stuck on how to get the output as a single list vs. strings.  Obviously I'm learning so kind assistance or suggestions are appreciated!

**Here is the assingment:**
Compute their Cartesian product, AxB of two lists. Each list has no more than 10 numbers.

For example, if the user supplies the two input lists:
A = [1,2]
B = [3,4]

then the Cartesian product output should be:
AxB = [(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]

**Here is what I've written so far:**

```
import itertools

input_A = []
input_B = []

input_A = input('Enter first 2 - 10 characters: ')
input_B = input('Enter second 2 - 10 characters: ')

for combination in itertools.product(input_A, input_B):
  print('AxB = ', [combination])
```

**Here is my output:**

```
Enter first 2 - 10 characters: 12 #I don't get the the below output when using comma separated items
Enter second 2 - 10 characters: 34
AxB =  [('1', '3')]
AxB =  [('1', '4')]
AxB =  [('2', '3')]
AxB =  [('2', '4')]
```

Comment: You're seeing this output because the `input()` function always returns a string. As an aside: are you sure your assignment is actually asking for you to take user input? I'm also assuming that since this is homework, your professor might be expecting you to write your own cartesian product function.

Comment: To clarify: if you enter `12` as `input_A` then `input_A == "12"`. If you instead enter `1,2` then `input_A == "1,2"`. If you indeed are required to accept input from the user, then you will need to write some logic to determine whether the input is numbers or letters, and whether you as the programmer want to enforce comma-separated values.

Comment: Problem with this professor is even when it doesn't explicitly say get user input he grades you down if you don't so I have to assume he wants one...  I did try entering 1,2 but the output included the ',' as an item instead of a separator.  Thanks for your suggestions, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Right, that's because you have no logic in place to separate your input based on the comma character. Hence why you're going to get a cartesian product where `","` is considered an element.

Comment: Also, again, I have a feeling your professor is expecting you to write your own cartesian product function, not use the built-in version.

Comment: That's possible, I just wish I understood how to do that...  Struggling to wrap my brain around this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's a very simple algorithm. For every item in `A` pair it with every item in `B`.

Comment: I clearly don't understand Python, I've been trying for days to get the right combination and nothing seems to get me close without using itertools, which I confirmed he does not want us to use.  I also confirmed we have to use user prompts.  This is getting very frustrating...

Comment: I've added an answer to help you on this.

Comment: Thanks, I wish my "professor" put as much effort into this as you have...  So I do have my user prompt working and I feel like I get what the code is supposed to do it's getting it in the right order that I'm struggling with.  I define cartesian then add the nested for statements and the print but all I get is the input then the prompt.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

```
import itertools

input_A = list(map(int, input("Enter multiple numbers for first list separated by commas: ").split(",")))
input_B = list(map(int, input("Enter multiple numbers for second list separated by commas: ").split(",")))
result = list(itertools.product(input_A, input_B))

print(f'A x B = {result}')

#output:
#Enter multiple numbers for first list separated by commas: 3,5,7
#Enter multiple numbers for second list separated by commas: 2,4
#A x B = [(3, 2), (3, 4), (5, 2), (5, 4), (7, 2), (7, 4)]
```

If you want to catch the exception when the user enters a non-numerical value and keep prompting the user for the correct input, you can do this:

```
import itertools

while True:
    try:
        input_A = list(map(int, input("Enter multiple numbers for first list separated by commas: ").split(",")))
        input_B = list(map(int, input("Enter multiple numbers for second list separated by commas: ").split(",")))
        result = list(itertools.product(input_A, input_B))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong input. Start over!")

print(f'A x B = {result}')
```

Comment: `itertools.product` can be directly passed to a `list` constructor; there's no need to use the accumulator pattern. Simply do `result = list(itertools.product(input_A, input_B))`. I also think you should explain your code to OP, and point out that this script is not safe against non-integer inputs from the user.

Comment: @blorgon Done! You are full of good suggestions tonight. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use `itertools`, let's build a function to compute the cartesian product of two sets, `A` and `B`. I'll assume you have your user input part of the script working.

I'm going to assume that you're not going to do any sort of duplicate removal (technically the cartesian product is performed on two *sets*, or collections of unique objects, but since you're doing user input, a user may give a list of items with duplicates and nothing in the instructions say anything about dealing with that).

As a small example, let `A = {0, 1, 2}` and `B = {3, 4, 5}`. Then the cartesian product is

```
{(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)}
```

Notice that from left to right, the first element of each tuple seems not to change often. The systematic way to generate this list of tuples is by first taking an element from `A` and "fixing" it in place while you take each element from `B` and pair them. So in pseudocode:

```
take 0 from A
    take 3 from B  ->  (0, 3)
    take 4 from B  ->  (0, 4)
    take 5 from B  ->  (0, 5)
    no more elements in B
take 1 from A
    take 3 from B  ->  (1, 3)
    take 4 from B  ->  (1, 4)
    .
    .
    .
```

Or even more succinctly: `for each item in A, pair it with an element from B`.

In Python:

```py
>>> for a in A:
...    for b in B:
...        print(f"({a}, {b})")
...
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(0, 5)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
```

I'll let you put the last piece in (get your results somehow, as all this code is doing is printing the values of `a` and `b` each iteration).

Comment: @KSparrow, I intentionally left out the last little piece of the puzzle for you to figure out. Right now all my code is doing is printing the tuples. You need to accumulate those tuples yourself. By "accumulate" I mean use the accumulator pattern. Initialize an empty container, and then just add the tuples to that container instead of printing them.

Comment: Thanks @blorgon, I'm trying to work through that now.  I have cartesian(list_A, list_B) and I know you can append but that is what I'm researching now.  I appreciate the help you've provided so far, like I said, I wish my professor was as interested in helping us understand as you've been.  The majority of the class seems to be in the same predicament...

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got it (as long as you don't use comma's or spaces in the user input anyway!)  This will have to do, the professor will mark down for what he doesn't like anyway so this is what I'm going with...  Thanks to everyone who threw out ideas, I clearly needed to walk away from it for a day to be able to see it more clearly.

```
def cartesian(list_A, list_B):
        AxB = [ ]
        for A in list_A:
            for B in list_B:
                    AxB.append((A,B))
        print('AxB =  ', AxB)

list_A = input('Enter up to 10 numbers for List A: ')

list_B = input('Enter up to 10 numbers for List B: ')

cartesian(list_A, list_B)
```

Output:

```
Enter up to 10 numbers for List A: 12
Enter up to 10 numbers for List B: 34
AxB =   [('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4')]
```